# how insert array values into table

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
(
    [0] => ('id', '2')
    [1] => ('name', 'Jhon')
)
```

And this is the for to insert, but doesen't works, please help ... any ideas?

```
function redeem() {
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json,true);
    $rows = array();
    foreach($obj as $key => $value)
    {
        $rows[] = "('" . $key . "', '" . $value . "')";
        error_log(print_r($rows,true));
    }
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO prueba (id,nombre) VALUES (%d,%s)',$value->id,$value->name) or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
    $stmt->execute();   
}
```

Comment: Where does your code error? On the execution of the sql. Or beforehand?

Comment: Probably on `$value->id` because it's a numerical array with an assoc-array in it. What would work is `$value[0]['id']` and `$value[1]['name']`

Comment: Try changing `$rows[] = "('" . $key . "', '" . $value . "')";` to `$rows[] = array($key,$value);` AND `$value->id,$value->name` to `$rows[0][1],$rows[1][1]`

Comment: It's not obvious to me what type of object $this->db is.  PDO?  MySQLi?  Does prepare even work like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function redeem() {
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json,true);
    // Assumes $obj == array(0 => $assocArray, 1 => $assocArray)
    foreach($obj as $index => $assocArray) {
        // Assumes $assocArray == array(0 => array('id' => '2'), 1 => array('name' => 'John'))
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO prueba (id,nombre) VALUES (%d,%s)',$assocArray[0]['id'],$assocArray[1]['name']) or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
        $stmt->execute();   
    }
}
```

Not elegant, but would probably work.
A lot of assumptions here and I'm getting sleepy *sigh*, but I also assume that `$this->db` is a class with a database wrapper because the prepare statement is like nothing I've ever seen before, a MySQL prep-statement should look something like:

```
$prep = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO prueba (id,nombre) VALUES (?,'?')")
$prep->bindParam(1, $assocArray[0]['id']);
$prep->bindParam(2, $assocArray[1]['name']);
$prep->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks Torxed. Yes, $this->db is a class. I fixed it but I have gotten this message...

Comment: PHP Warning:  mysqli::prepare() expects exactly 1 parameter, 3 given in
 /home/fut/public_html/WebService/test_subir2.php on line 45, this line is the INSERT command

Comment: @user3711971 Did you solve the exception? Because the prepare statement for SQLite is different from MySQL in PHP, i think.. rarely use SQLite :P